# Upgrade to Kubuntu 15.04 broke settings and Akonadi

Tags: kde, 15.04

I have upgraded from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 on one machine and all a lot of the KDE settings are  reset to default. The position of the Plasma Panel was back to default, the background image back to the default.

After a bit of digging I found that `~/.kde/env/` moved to `~/.config/plasma-session/env`, but where did the remainder go?

How do I migrate the settings?

---

I found a comment on [Heise Open](http://www.heise.de/forum/Open-Source/News-Kommentare/Linux-Distribution-Ubuntu-15-04-ist-fertig/Re-bringts-kde5/posting-3300379/show/) which said that all the settings have to be re-applied and that a MySQL upgrade broke Akonadi. This can be circumvented by installing MariaDB instead of MySQL or by switching the backend to SQLite by installing `akonadi-backend-sqlite` and changing the backend with `kcmshell4 akonadi`.

Comment: can you be more specific with switching the backend? Where are akonadi settings files, which directory are they in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expand on what was said earlier despite being pretty much a novice, I've just managed to change the backend to SQLite and it's got things working again.Akonadi has a GUI config that can be used to change the backend database type.

What I did to switch top SQLite was:

First install SQLite support with the command

```
sudo apt-get install akonadi-backend-sqlite
```

then once that's completed run the command

```
kcmshell4 akonadi
```

in the terminal to display the Akonadi setup GUI.

Once the GUI is running, I selected the Akonadi Server Tab and changed the Database Driver drop-down list from the default of MySQL to SQLite (all the configuration options on the page disappeared when I did this)

I then just pressed the Apply button and the Start button and the server then started up without further problems.

Comment: Just to be specific, you can also set the driver to use Postgres which seems to work.